# Is there a way to change the symbol shape in a ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I made a plot using ggplot in R and wanted to have labels with the values that correspond with each of the points on the plot. I used the function geom_label_repel to get the labels on the plot, but it seems like it changed the legend to a letter instead of a dot, which I don't really like. Is there a way to change the shape of the symbol in the legend to a dot instead?

Here's the code for my plot:

```
ggplot(CI_bar_df_null, mapping = aes(x = model, y = R2, color = condition, group = condition)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label_repel(
    label = CI_bar_df_null$R2factor, 
    nudge_x = .3, nudge_y = 0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = CI_lower, ymax = CI_upper), width = .3) +
  #ylim(-.06, .6)
  ggtitle('Model R-Squared Values and Confidence Intervals') +
  ylab('R-Squared Value') +
  xlab('Model Type') +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Condition") +
  scale_shape_discrete(shape = 17)
```

[image: Here's the plot with the legend that I don't like]

Comment: could you provide `dput(CI_bar_df_null)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the `show.legend = F` argument inside `geom_label_repel`. This will avoid creating a legend for `geom_label_repel` and leave intact the other two legends (`geom_point` and `geom_line`).

```
geom_label_repel(
    label = mtcars$cyl, 
    nudge_x = .3, 
    nudge_y = 0, 
    show.legend = F)
```